# Recursive Call with goog.dom.animationFrame

Tags: clojurescript, google-closure-library

I am trying to use google closure animationFrame feature.
I would like to create an animation task with it and to call that created task recursively.

I defined a def named animationTask.
When I try to use that def recursively in that task it fails. It logs out that animationTask is undefined and thus can not be used as a function.

[image]

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?
I feel like I am missing some basic clojure knowledge here.

Comment: You are calling (animationTask) as a function, but is not defined as such. You should define it using (defn animationTask [] ...)

Comment: i don't think that's it. ganimation/createTask does produce a function

Comment: Do you want the value under `:measure` to be a function? In other words, replace `do` with `fn [state]`? (Same argument for `:mutate`)

Comment: Please post all code dirextly here as text.

Comment: As an aside, you will probably want to use `#js` on the argument being passed to `ganimation/createTask`, otherwise you are passing a persistent map instead of a JavaScript object.

Comment: thanks adding `#js` and replacing `do` with`fn` fixed my mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is calling the animation task function before it is defined. It is analogous to this simpler code:

```
(defn create [x] (fn []))

(def task (create {:measure (task)}))
```

If you try that in a REPL, you'll see that `task` is being called while it is still undefined.

Instead, the value under `:measure` is supposed to be a function, and the API takes a JavaScript object. This would be analogous to revising the above example to be:

```
(def task (create #js {:measure (fn [state] (task))}))
```